# Cannot maximize application window of Skype and Anydesk in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, skype, maximized, anydesk

I am not able to maximize the application window of Skype and Anydesk apps to full height and width just like other apps in Ubuntu 20.04.
This problem seems to be for the Ubuntu 20.04 version because in my other PC with Ubuntu 18.04 it is working properly.

Please see the screenshots of both app-window in **Ubuntu 20.04**.

See the Skype screenshot:

[image]

See the Anydesk screenshot
[image]

Can anyone give an idea of how I can enable the maximize option for these two apps?

Comment: how did you install anydesk ?

Comment: Using debian installer